# Fast changing bitmaps in Android

Tags: android, android-canvas

Link for pictures: https://i.stack.imgur.com/MpNBc.jpg

I am using Canvas to make animations for my android application. I have onDraw method where everything is moving or rotating and every animation is perfect. But when i try to change animations like on the second picture it is stuck like there for 1-2 sec and then it goes on the third picture.
As you can see the application is about Weather and every condition is animation.

Any ideas how I could solve this?

This is for the first picture in onDraw method:

```
else {
        if (unknown == null) {
            recycleBitmap();
            condition = 0;
            unknown = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),
                    R.drawable.unknown);
            width = getLayoutParams().width;
            height = getLayoutParams().height;
            width = width - (width / 7);
            height = height - (height / 7);
            unknown = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(unknown, (int) width,
                    (int) height, true);
            initWeatherIcon();
        }
        drawUnknown1((getLayoutParams().width - unknown.getWidth()) / 2,
                ((getLayoutParams().height - unknown.getHeight()) / 2),
                canvas);
```

This is the code for the third picture:

```
else if (condition == 6) {
        matrix.reset();
        matrix.setTranslate(getLayoutParams().height / 2,
                icon.getHeight() / 3);
        matrix.postRotate(x, getLayoutParams().width / 2
                + getLayoutParams().width / 4,
                icon.getHeight() / 3 + icon.getHeight() / 2);
        x++;
        RectF rect4 = new RectF(100, 100, 100, 100);
        matrix.mapRect(rect4);
        canvas.drawBitmap(icon, matrix, new Paint());

        drawCloudSun(
                0,
                getLayoutParams().height
                        - (getLayoutParams().height / 2 + getLayoutParams().height / 4),
                canvas);
        invalidate();
```

There is If-else to call animations. When the application is started it is called unknown.png but when the condition is changed to Cloudy it enters in appropriate if-else statement and there the problem occur.

Comment: Please post some of your code.

Comment: Yes... code is required to pinpoint the problem: Wild guess: You are loading resources in onDraw.